# Bios Clears Itself

Tags: windows-7, windows, bios, reset, bsod

For whatever reason, my computer regularly bluescreens.  Oftentimes when it bluescreens the bios gets cleared.  I doubt the CMOS battery is bad, as it is relatively new (the same with the power supply), so what do you guys think would clear a bios like that?

My system is a self built machine, running windows 7.

Comment: Something on your mainboard might be short-circuiting. A forgotten case screw or a loose ended cable perhaps? Other than that, CMOS battery comes to mind, but it wouldn't cause Bluescreens.

Comment: Yeah, good idea, I'll test that out when I get back from school today.

Comment: have you checked out the dump files typically located in %systemroot%\minidump (normally c:\windows\minidump). There is program called "WhoCrashed" Which makes it a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the two problems are related, but it could be. Try power off the computer and unplug it from the AC outlet. Wait 10 mins. If you power it up and the BIOS settings are cleared you have a bad CMOS battery.
For the bluescreens it could be anything. What type of message do you get on it?

Comment: It changes, but irq_less_than_or_equal, bad_pool_header, and one or two others that I can't remember right now.

Comment: Sounds like a RAM issue to me.

Comment: Yeah, you would think.  I borrowed a (known) good stick of ram from a friend and left it as the only thing in there and the computer ran great for a month, then started blue screening again.

Answer (score 1):

If you are by any chance overclocking your CPU, this might be the fall-back mechanism of the mainboard, so that the system returns to the last known running state and boots fine.

Solution: Set the BIOS to factory defaults and run it like this for a while.